# WPF PowerPoint Application without Office installed

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, powerpoint

I am looking to create an application with WPF that will be able to display Powerpoints without any instance of Office installed on the machine. I also want to do this without any conversion to video such as a wmv file. I have looked into displaying it in a web browser; however, that requires Office to be installed for the conversion and Office 2013 no longer supports saving Powerpoints as HTML.

I currently have a solution running on a WinForm embedded into a WPF application but it requires Office on the machine. Any help/advice on this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities I can think of:

Learn the PPTX (and possibly PPT binary) file format and rewrite huge chunks of PPT yourself

Use the free PPT viewer to do the heavy lifting.  I don't believe it can be automated but there might be enough functionality for what you need.  Whether this meets the "without any instance of Office installed on the machine" criterion or not is up to you.  If you don't want to install Office because of the cost, the viewer's free.  Problem solved.